# Multiclass Classification: Should the number of output neurons should be equal to number of classes (My model has no softmax)

Tags: python, pytorch, classification, torch

I am using `Pytorch` for my CNN.
I trained the model with [CrossEntropyLoss](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss.html#torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss) and [Adam Optimizer](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.optim.Adam.html). I have a dataset with `5 number of classes`.
The last layer of my model produces `output shape  = [Batch_Size, 400]`. I am not using the Softmax function for this Classification. The model produced *97% accuracy*.
I can not post my model architecture here, for some reason.

My doubt is `Is it it rule of thumb that the number of output neurons` *(400 in my case)* `should always be equal to the number of classes` *(5 in my case)*. If so, does this have to be followed even if the model has `no softmax` function?  If not, my model is good, right?

Note: I did an extensive search about the topics mentioned. But they did not solve my problem, that is why I am posting it here to know.

Comment: How are you mapping your 400 outputs to the 5 classes you're interested in? Are you only looking at 5 of them?

Comment: After I get the predicted outputs `y_predict = model(images.to(device)) ` which is of shape `[Batch_Size, 400]`. I used `_, pred_labels = torch.max(y_predict, 1)` to get the predicted labels, which is of shape `[Batch_Size]`. Then I compared it with actual labels of that batch `true_labels` using `running_corrects += torch.sum(pred_labels == true_labels.data.to(device))` to get the number of corrects.

Comment: 1. I assume true_labels only has 5 possible values. So you're training the model to predict large negative values for positions 5 - 400. What is the value of this? Did you check the outputs, is this what happens? What is the value of learning that? 2. Saying that the model has 97% accuracy is not very useful. I can predict if a day of the year is your birthday with >99% accuracy, that doesn't mean I know your birthday.

Comment: Yes. true_labels only has 5 values in between 0 to 4. But the [torch.max(tensor, dimension)](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.max.html) gives the largest maximum value and its index in that dimension, not the largest negative value. For positions 5 to 400 in the `pred_labels` in every row all values are coming zero. I checked multiple times, `for all rows all the values between column indices 5 to 400 are zero`. So `_, pred_labels = torch.max(y_predict, 1)` is giving the maximum values in between indices 0 to 4 for each row of `y_predict`

Comment: Well, you didn't want to share your model, so I could only guess. I assume you use relu activation in that layer. Basically, you're just wasting lots of computation time with all the values that are trivial 0, that's why it's recommended to have the same number of output values as classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're wasting lots of computation time, throwing away most of your output by computing 400 numbers and only considering 5.

Pytorch's `CrossEntropyLoss` automatically applies a softmax (technically a logsoftmax) to the outputs of your neural network to compute the loss.

At inference time, I'd also recommend you apply a softmax to get more readable outputs (you can consider the softmax output to be a probability). To do so, you'd use: `torch.nn.functional.softmax(y_predict[:, :5])`.

You should consider retraining your model with the correct number of outputs, which will not hurt performance and will accelerate the model size and speed. You could also directly extract the weights you're using from the pretrained model, as such:

```py
import torch
trained_layer = torch.nn.Linear(50, 400)

new_layer = torch.nn.Linear(50, 5)
new_layer._parameters["weight"] = trained_layer._parameters["weight"][:5, :].clone()
new_layer._parameters["bias"] = trained_layer._parameters["bias"][:5].clone()
```

Comment: Thank you. So it is not necessary to use `Softmax` in every multiclass classification, right?

Comment: A softmax will usually be there somewhere. The raw outputs of your model are not very useful, what you want is a probability distribution over classes, which you get with a softmax. During training, the important thing is to avoid accidentally applying a softmax several times, for example once manually then once again in the loss. `CrossEntropyLoss` operates on logits (raw outputs), and consists of `LogSoftMax + NLLLoss`. If you'd used a softmax directly in your model, you would've needed to use a `NLLLoss`  (+ `log`) instead.

Comment: Thank you for the interpretation of the extraction of weights. But I am training an entirely new model. So I can not use last layer weights in the next layer which is also under training. Did you mean to define `torch.nn.Linear(50, 5)` at inference time after `y_predict = model(images.to(device))`?

Comment: If you're training the model from scratch, you should be able to simply modify its architecture so the last layer has an output of size 5. I'm not sure I understand the issue you're facing.

Comment: I tried modifying the architecture, but it is effecting the accuracy.

Answer (score 1):

the sigmoid activation function works too when multi classes classify. if the output tensors don't equal to the classes, it should be larger than the classes. the remained tensors is useless.

\\

one image with one label, 3 classes totally

predict P=[0.1, 0.1, 0.6], can use sigmoid(P)
or use softmax(P)

\
one image with multi box and multi label, one box only have one label, 3 classes totally

predict P=[[0.1, 0.1, 0.6], [0.2, 0.3, 0.9]], can use sigmoid(P)

or use softmax(P, dim = -1)

Comment: You mean using [torch.nn.Sigmoid](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Sigmoid.html#torch.nn.Sigmoid) or [torch.sigmoid](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.sigmoid.html).     [This link](https://www.quora.com/Why-is-it-better-to-use-Softmax-function-than-sigmoid-function) and [This link](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/39264/how-does-sigmoid-activation-work-in-multi-class-classification-problems) is saying that `Softmax`  is preferred over `Sigmoid` when each input has one label, which is my case. Is it true? Can I use it?

Comment: if one inputs just have one label,  sigmoid or softmax are all good, you can try both. but softmax is better than sigmoid in this case. sigmoid is used in multi classes.

Comment: Thanks. But How to use `sigmoid`. I have never used it for classification. Should I define `_sigmoid = torch.nn.Sigmoid()` and use `y_predict = _sigmoid(y_predict)` after `y_predict = model(images.to(device)) ` Just like how `Softmax` is used. But this doesn't convert `[Batch_Size, 400]` to `[Batch_Size, 5] (Or) is it now how to use it. Could you tell me.

Comment: you should use **[[batch_size, 2+3]]**

Comment: Didn't get it. How to do it. Could you explain please.

Comment: You should be using a softmax if you're solving a multi-class problem (aka each input is assigned to exactly one category), as indicated by the links. You can then do `torch.nn.functional.softmax(y_predict[:, :5])`. But you really should consider retraining your model with the correct architecture (5 outputs).